# JaxWS Webservice configuration file was not loaded

Tags: java, jax-ws

Hi I've written a WSDL File and generated my Web-Service. Wen I now want to call the service like this:

```
res = new UpdateCatalogWebService().getUpdateCatalogPort().updateCatalog(updateRequest);
```

I got an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - MASM0003: Default [ jaxws-tubes-default.xml ] configuration file was not loaded
```

What does this error mean? and how can I fix this error?

Edit: I'am Using Netbeans

Comment: Does nobody have an Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an problem of your Netbeans-Environment or your Netbeans installation. In case of this you can try to run your application With Eclipse. I think it will run perfectly.!